# How to output using CR (Carriage Return) instead of LF (Line Feed) in sqlite?

Tags: csv, sqlite

I am trying to output into a csv file and have used the following commands:

```
once output.csv;
select * from table;
```

With the above command, it will output a csv file that uses a LF to represent a line break. Is there anyway to change the settings so it will use a CR instead of a LF when outputting a file?

Note: I can open it up with excel but this will be a hassle if I am exporting multiple files.

Comment: Check [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html).

Answer (score 7):

Since version 3.8.6, you can use the `.separator` command to also define the record separator in CSV mode:

```
.mode csv
.separator , "\r"
.once output.csv
select * from mytable;
```